# DispatchAction Functionality in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a .jsp page in which i have four buttons named submit,add,update and delete as:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="User" >
    <s:submit />
    <s:submit action="addUser" value="Add" />
    <s:submit action="updateUser" value="Update" />
    <s:submit action="deleteUser" value="Delete" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

On each submit it is being redirected to action class as mentioned in my struts.xml file as:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="User" class="vaannila.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="addUser" method="add" class="vaannila.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="updateUser" method="update" class="vaannila.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="deleteUser" method="delete" class="vaannila.UserAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

and finally to the corresponding method of the action class as :

```
package vaannila;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{

    private String message;

    public String execute()
    {
          System.out.println("Inside execute method");
        message = "Inside execute method";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String add()
    {
          System.out.println("Inside add method");
        message = "Inside add method";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String update()
    {
        message = "Inside update method";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String delete()
    {
        message = "Inside delete method";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

When i click on Submit button it goes to execute method which is fine. But when i click on Add button or any other button again it get redirected to execute method instead of add method. What am i doing wrong?
Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you are using Struts2 version `2.3.15.3` or above you need to set `struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled` constant to true in order to enable support for `action:` prefix.

Put that in your `struts.xml` file:

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also specify this in the properties file : struts.properties

struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled=true

For more info : http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/constant-configuration.html