# Struts 2.3 form with multiple submit tags with action attribute doesn't work

Tags: java, struts2

I have a form like this:

```
<s:form>
<s:submit action="act1"  />
<s:submit action="act2"  />
</s:form>
```

on generated html i have :

```
<input type="submit" name="action:act1">
<input type="submit" name="action:act2">
```

Now with struts2.3 it doesn't work but with struts 2.0 its all ok.

The log says that the parameter: `action:act1` is in the excludeParams

The problem is in `params` interceptor:
on the `defaultStack` i version 2.3 there is a filter like `^action:.*` for  interceptor `params` interceptor.

struts-default-xml:

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
<interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
<interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
<interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
<interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
<interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
<interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
<interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
<interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
<interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
<interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
<interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
<interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
<interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
<interceptor-ref name="params">
<param name="excludeParams">^dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request
\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,^parameters
\..*,^action:.*,^method:.*</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
<param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="workflow">
<param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
<interceptor-ref name="deprecation"/>
</interceptor-stack>
```

What can i do ?
 thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19832617/1700321.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exclude the submit action from a list of parameters in struts2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764609/how-to-exclude-the-submit-action-from-a-list-of-parameters-in-struts2)

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit your `struts.xml` file. Add the following line to it

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true" />
```