# Multi action in struts form

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin, struts2-namespace

I want to add 3 button into struts form. My code is :

```
@Action("/admin/product/insert")
public String insert() throws Exception {
    if(upload.hasFile()){
        model.setImage(upload.getFileFileName());
        upload.saveTo("../images/customers/");
    }
    else{
        model.setImage("product.png");
    }
    XHibernate.save(model);
    return "new";
}

@Action("/admin/product/update")
public String update() throws Exception {
    if(upload.hasFile()){
        model.setImage(upload.getFileFileName());
        upload.saveTo("../images/customers/");
    }
    System.out.println("update");
    XHibernate.update(model);
    return "input";
}

@Action("/admin/product/delete")
public String delete() throws Exception {
    XHibernate.delete(model);
    return "new";
}
```

In jsp:

```xml
<s:form enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple" role="form">

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="id">Product Id</label>
        <s:textfield id="productId" name="id" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="name">Product Name</label>
        <s:textfield name="name" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="unitPrice">Unit Price</label>
        <s:textfield name="unitPrice" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="unitBrief">Unit Description</label>
        <s:textfield name="unitBrief" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="discount">Discount</label>
        <s:textfield name="discount" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <s:textfield name="quantity" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="productDate">Product Date</label>
        <s:textfield name="productDate" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="supplier.id">Supplier</label>
        <s:select name="supplier.id" list="suppliers" listKey="id"
            listValue="name" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="category.id">Category</label>
        <s:select name="category.id" list="categories" listKey="id"
            listValue="name" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Features</label>
        <div>
            <label><s:checkbox name="available" /> Available</label> <label><s:checkbox
                    name="special" /> Special</label> <label><s:checkbox
                    name="latest" /> latest</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="image">Image</label> <input id="image" type="file"
            name="upload.file">
        <s:hidden name="image" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <s:textarea id="index_description" name="description" rows="30"
            cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <s:submit value="Thêm mới" action="admin/product/insert"
            cssClass="btn btn-default" />
        <s:submit value="Cập nhật" action="admin/product/update"
            cssClass="btn btn-default" />
        <s:submit value="Xóa" action="admin/product/delete" cssClass="btn btn-default" />
        <a href="product/index" class="btn btn-default">Nhập lại</a>
    </div>
</s:form>
```

The problem is it can't call the exactly action.

I always got the error: " There is no Action mapped for namespace /admin/product and action name admin/product/update.".

Do i have to split it to 3 forms ? OR Is there any way to have 3 buttons for 3 actions in 1 form like my code ? Any help would be great.

updated the logging when enable devmode:

```
ognl.MethodFailedException: Method "setDiscount" failed for object eshop.entity.Product@48e4d3df [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setDiscount([Ljava.lang.String;)]
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:823)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:964)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:75)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:131)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:28)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1656)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.CompoundRootAccessor.setProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:50)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1656)
at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:101)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:177)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:246)
at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:476)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:192)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:155)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:273)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: try to have different names in each submit button.

Comment: i tried but it still not works

Comment: if you have one submit button, does it work?

Comment: if i have one button i put the actions in form tag and it worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13343954/1700321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your current problem, you should add

```xml
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
```

in struts.xml, that is false by default, and will take all the part before the last slash as namespace instead of action name. BTW this has side effects:

> [**Action Names With Slashes**](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionNames)
>
> If your action names have slashes in them (for example, 
>   
>   `<action name="admin/home" class="tutorial.Admin"/>`) you need to specifically
>   allow slashes in your action names via a constant in the struts.xml
>   file by specifying
>
> `<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>`.
>
> See [JIRA Issue WW-1383](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1383) for discussion as **there are
>   side effects to setting this property to true**.

To fix the problem ***the right way***, you need to make a correct usage of namespaces:

Action

```java
@Namespace("/admin/product")
public class YourAction extends ActionSupport

    @Action("insert")
    public String insert() throws Exception {
        /* .... */
    }

    @Action("update")
    public String update() throws Exception {
        /* .... */
    }

    @Action("delete")
    public String delete() throws Exception {
        /* .... */
    }
```

JSP

```xml
<s:submit value="Thêm mới" action="insert" cssClass="btn btn-default" />
<s:submit value="Cập nhật" action="update" cssClass="btn btn-default" />
<s:submit value="Xóa"      action="delete" cssClass="btn btn-default" />
```

You should also refactor the package structure for Actions and JSPs to follow the namespace structure.

P.S: remember to set action prefix enabled as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25907546/1654265) if you are using a Struts2 version higher than **2.3.15.2**:

```xml
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.enabled" value="true"/>
```

---

**EDIT**

If the `namespace` of the Action you are using to show your JSP is **not** the same of the actions called (in this case, `/admin/product`), you need to specify it in `<s:form>` tag:

```xml
<s:form namespace = "/admin/product" 
          enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
            theme = "simple" 
             role = "form">
```

And (if you are using a Struts2 version higher than **2.3.15.2**), set the following property in struts.xml:

```xml
<constant name="struts.mapper.action.prefix.crossNamespaces" value="true"/>
```

because it has been disabled by default [due to security reason](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-018.html).

Comment: sorry i'm busy for a day, I will try your suggest and reply to you asap. thanks for your support

Comment: It's strange. I followed your suggest, 3 buttons worked but when i click insert, the form doesn't call the insert(only form change to insert action) then i click update(the insert action show up in URL) then i click delete(the update action show up in URL). Look like the action was prevent by something and stack there. But only the URL change, the code in controller doesn't fire.

Comment: How have you defined the INPUT result ? Please enable devMode and check carefully server logs and app logs for a stacktrace

Comment: Please check my update for logs in the console when i click the action.

Comment: Are you using an old version of Struts2 ? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2971

Comment: Yes i use version 2.1.6 . Is there anyway to solve the problem without change version of struts ?

Comment: Woah, gotcha with a long shot! :O BTW no, unless you don't want to patch it yourself. Believe me, upgrade to 2.3.16.3, you will have A LOT of advantages, including security fixes and functionalities, with very few adjustments... already listed in this answer! :)

Comment: it took me 2 hours to gather library to integrate struts 2.3.16.3 and hibernate and now it's still not work. Can you show me the list of compatible library of latest struts and hibernate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66053/discussion-between-anh-nguyen-and-andrea-ligios).